# data-role="form" gives error in W3C Validator

Tags: contact-form, w3c-validation, html4

A friend of mine has a website with this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I know it is an old doctype.

The problem is, that on the contact page it gives a Data-Role error in the W3C Validator.

The contact form is from 123contactform. I already contacted them, but they only come up with the solution to change the doctype.
For now I don't want to do that, because then I get a lot of other errors, that I have to fix.

How can I change the Data-Role error? Here is the error in the W3C Validator: https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maryderekboedelopruiming.nl%2Fcontact.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change the doctyp. All is well now.